# Summation of squared 3-j symbol

Tags: quantum-mechanics, formal-proofs, quantum-field-theory, coupling

There is a property for the [3-j symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-j_symbol) as

$$
\sum_{m_1 m_2 m_3}
\begin{pmatrix}
j_1 & j_2 & j_3 \\
m_1 & m_2 & m_3
\end{pmatrix}^2 = \Delta (j_1, j_2, j_3),
$$
where $ \Delta (j_1, j_2, j_3)$ is the triangular condition i.e. if it is satisfied, it equals to the unit otherwise is zero.

I have checked this property numerically and it's working well. However, I need to **prove it analytically**. How can I figure it out? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to write this in terms of Clebsch-Gordan coefficients? Their 2nd orthogonality relation?

Comment: Yes, but it did not work out.

Comment: Dear @CosmasZachos, there is a difference between the equation typed in the question and your answer. In the question there are three indices for the summation while you have two summation indices.

Comment: That is because the correct identity has two, of course: the sum of the three ms must vanish! You have also messed up the over all factor, which I corrected.

Answer (score 1):

I fear you have misconfigured something. The standard orthogonality condition reflecting the unitarity of the 3-j symbols, as checked in WP, $m_3=m_3'=-m_1-m_2$, $j_3'=j_3$ is
$$
(2j_3+1)\sum_{m_1, m_2}
\begin{pmatrix}
j_1 & j_2 & j_3 \\
m_1 & m_2 & m_3
\end{pmatrix}^2 = \Delta (j_1, j_2, j_3),
$$
so, expressible in terms of the CG coefficients, the [orthogonality condition of the CG reduction matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clebsch%E2%80%93Gordan_coefficients#Orthogonality_relations),
$$
    \sum_{m_1, m_2}
      \langle j_3 \, m_3 | j_1 \, m_1 \, j_2 \, m_2 \rangle
      \langle j_1 \, m_1 \, j_2 \, m_2 | j_3 \, m_3 \rangle =  \Delta (j_1, j_2, j_3).
$$
The triangular condition is baked into the definition of CG coefficients, so it is implied when one writes this "second" orthogonality condition out, as physicists learn in elementary QM the conditions of the reduction of $j_1\otimes j_2$ and apply them as they breathe.